# Django - foreign key - invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123453-11-32'

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

First of all, I think the error is incurred because Django is expecting integer, but instead a string is passed. The problem is, I don't know why and where Django is expecting integer.

**Error Message**

```
ValueError at /well_list/123453-11-32/contextual/bha/1
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123453-11-32'
```

**models.py**

```
class WellInfo(models.Model):
    api = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    well_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BHA_List(models.Model):
    well = models.ForeignKey(WellInfo, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_list')
    bha_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**app/urls.py**

```
app_name = 'contextual'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', base_views.ContextualMain_DetailView.as_view(), name='main'),
    re_path(r'^bha/(?P<pk_alt>[-\w]+)$', base_views.BHA_UpdateView.as_view(), name='bha'),
]
```

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('well_list/', include([

        re_path(r'^$', views.WellList_ListView.as_view(), name='well_list'),
        re_path(r'^create/$', views.AddWell_CreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
        re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/contextual/', include('contextual.urls')),

        ]))
]
```

**context_processors.py**

```
def add_context_to_base(request):

    print('context_processor was called')

    try:
        api = resolve(request.path_info).kwargs['pk']
        default_page_1 = '1'

        return {'api': api, 'default_page_1': default_page_1}

    except KeyError:

        return {}
```

The reason I added `context_processor` is because the string in url `123453-11-32` was injected into **base.html** using `context_processor`. I'm not sure if this is the source of error. But I don't think this was the source of error, because it did not print `context_processor was called` on the console.

And finally, this is my views.py that gives me the error:

**views.py**

```
class BHA_UpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'bha_test.html'
    context_object_name = 'bha'
    model = models.BHA_List
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('well_list')
```

But if I change my model, and set it `model = models.WellInfo`, it works just fine. Looks like there's something wrong with my `BHA_list` model because it has `ForeignKey`. Can anyone help whats wrong with my codes?

Edit:

I figured out the source of error. By default, Django set `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'`. `(?P<pk>[-\w]+)` pattern was already used when I called `ContextualMain_DetailView`, so I had to declare a separate `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'` for my `BHA_UpdateView`.

Comment: From where you got that url? Is it from template? Another issue is for 'pk' `<pk>[-\w+]` pattern should be `<pk>\d+` as it contains digits not letters.

Comment: Your code expects `pk_alt` as integers whereas you are giving `Non-Integers`

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge that's obvious, so I stated it in the beginning